# HTML5 History API

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement this like this:

```
<a href="#" 
   onclick='pushstate(function1(),"title",function1) return false;'>
   Function1
</a>
```

This link works so my AJAX comes onto the page. However when I call the `onpopstate` when the back button is pressed, the function doesn't get recalled. When I alert my `event.state` I get undefined. How can I implement this, so that I can actually call back my function when the back button is pressed?

Comment: I now posted the code sorry I forgot to add it

Comment: I assume, instead if `function1()`, you want `function1`, but I don't know whether this solves your overall problem.

Comment: in the pushstate if i use function1 the function is not executed. If i use function1(), the function executes the ajax call but if I press the back button the url changes to the correct one but the function does not execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to capture the `popstate` event on the window, how are trying to intercept it at the moment?

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
    //restore the state here
}
```

[Here's a full tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: i have a popstate function. it is as follows `window.onpopstate = popstatehandler;` the function on popstatehandler is as follows `function popstatehandler(event) {if(event.state != null){ event.state();}}` the handler is initiated onload.

Comment: @KernElliott `event.state` is not a function, it's an object.  Your code is responsible for taking the information out of that object and rendering your page.

Comment: Ok understood but I don't have any information to create the function it juss runs so how will I recall the function when I go back to that page. Can I just make `event.state=function1();` based on the url information it receives?

Comment: @KernElliott Did you read the article I linked to?  In your `pushstate` function you store all the information you'll need, in the `popstate` function you grab that information and restore the state of the page.

Comment: I will go over it again but for some reason I cannot wrap my head around that concept of rebuilding the function